# Angular Interpolation is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, interpolation, syncfusion, ng-template

I have one sample with interpolation. It shows drop-down values correctly when is use any one event like below:

> sample: [click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-234dlf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**code snippet:**

*Here i have added event **(open)="onOpen()"***

```html
<ejs-dropdownlist 
    (open)="onOpen()"
    required id="ddlApp" name="ddlApp" [dataSource]='appDataSource' [allowFiltering]='true' 
    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" [valueTemplate]="valueTemplate" [(ngModel)]="dropdownlApp" 
    #ddlApp="ngModel" [placeholder]='ddlAppText' [fields]='fields'>
```

> sample 2: [click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrg6sc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**In this sample i would not add any event, in this case interolation is not working.**

**Code snippet:**

```html
<ejs-dropdownlist 
   required id="ddlApp" name="ddlApp" 
   [dataSource]='appDataSource' [allowFiltering]='true' 
   [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" [valueTemplate]="valueTemplate" 
   [(ngModel)]="dropdownlApp" #ddlApp="ngModel" 
   [placeholder]='ddlAppText' [fields]='fields'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` form your `@Component` decorator your second sample will work

You component decorator should read as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
```

Bind you object array in `ngOnInit()` it is the right way to bind and right time to bind the values - Thanks, Happy coding !!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But my issue is when i use changeDetection,interpolation is not working

Comment: As per your code `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` will check only once when the component is instantiated, so that causes issue and your model is not updating after component is instantiated if you want `changeDetection` then use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` this will check always when there is a change in your properties

Comment: If we remove ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush from component then that component will be checked on any changes in any component of app. If we're working on a performant application then we should keep OnPush. Adding `(open)="0"` event should be enough to update template when we open dropdown. Angular will automatically set DropDownListComponent to be checked so that the template attached to its view will be also checked.

Comment: @yurzui, i have same question. why i have to change onpush to default. if i use default it will trigger changedetection, if any changes occur but if we use onpush, it will trigger changedetection when value has been changed

Comment: `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is the only thing that made your change not to work in the sample 2 to so i have just suggested to remove it for this scenario - architecture of the application is based on your need - you problem was adding the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` if you want the same strategy you can use your same sample one